# Strange focus behavior for simple WPF ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, focus, itemscontrol, itemtemplate, keyboard-navigation

I'm seeing strange behavior when it comes to focus and keyboard navigation. In the example below I have a simple ItemsControl that has been templated so that it presents a list of CheckBoxes bound to the ItemsSource.

```
<ItemsControl FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=TheWindow, Path=ListOStrings}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

For some strange reason the *FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"* assignment causes keyboard focus to fail to be set when checking a checkbox via a mouse click and for focus to jump out of the ItemsControl when a check box is checked using the space bar on the keyboard. Both symptoms seem to point to some strange navigation happening when the checkbox is checked but I'm having a hard time getting to the bottom of it.

This problem occurs if I set any parent element up the visual tree as a focus scope using this method. If I remove the *FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"* then the problems go away. Unfortunately I'm seeing this problem in a larger project where I cannot just remove these focus scopes without worrying about other focus related consequences.

Could somebody explain to me the strange behavior I'm seeing? Is this a bug or am I just completely missing something?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This article explains it very well: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/EnhancedFocusScope.aspx

> **For What was FocusScope Designed?**
>
> Microsoft uses FocusScope in WPF to
>   create a temporary secondary focus.
>   Every ToolBar and Menu in WPF has its
>   own focus scope.
>
> With this knowledge, we can clearly
>   see why we have those problems:
>
> A toolbar button should not execute
>   commands on itself, but on whatever
>   had focus before the toolbar was
>   clicked. To accomplish this, routed
>   commands ignore the focus from focus
>   scopes and use the 'main' logical
>   focus instead. This explains why
>   routed commands don't work inside
>   focus scopes.
>
> Why does the large text box in the
>   test application screenshot still
>   display a caret? I don't know the
>   answer to this - but why shouldn't it?
>   Granted, the text box doesn't have the
>   keyboard focus (the small text box in
>   the WPF focus scope has that); but it
>   still has the main logical focus in
>   the active Window and is the receiver
>   of all routed commands.

*And this part covers the behavior you're seeing*

> Why does the keyboard focus move to
>   the large text box when you tab to the
>   CheckBox in the WPF focus scope and
>   press Space to toggle it?
>
> Well, this is exactly what you expect
>   when you click a menu item or a
>   toolbar: the keyboard focus should
>   return to the main focus. All
>   ButtonBase-derived controls will do
>   this.

Comment: +1 for an explanation of the problem. I just added the implementation of the IsEnhancedFocusScope attached behavior.

Comment: The only thing that I still don't understand given this explanation is that if I take another example where I set a grid to be the focus scope with a bunch of children that are buttons and check boxes, when I click on one of these checkboxes I don't see the strange loss of focus behavior that I see in my ItemsControl. Why does this only seem to affect checkboxes within an ItemsControl, is it something to do with the ScrollViewer, ItemsPresenter, ...?

Answer (score 11):

@Meleak explained the problem very well. Please read the article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/EnhancedFocusScope.aspx to fully understand what the problem is and how to solve it. I will just add the complete implementation of `IsEnhancedFocusScope` attached behavior mentioned in the article:

```
public static class FocusExtensions
{
    private static bool SettingKeyboardFocus { get; set; }

    public static bool GetIsEnhancedFocusScope(DependencyObject element) {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(IsEnhancedFocusScopeProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsEnhancedFocusScope(DependencyObject element, bool value) {
        element.SetValue(IsEnhancedFocusScopeProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnhancedFocusScopeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "IsEnhancedFocusScope",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(FocusExtensions),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsEnhancedFocusScopeChanged));

    private static void OnIsEnhancedFocusScopeChanged(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        var item = depObj as UIElement;
        if (item == null)
            return;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue) {
            FocusManager.SetIsFocusScope(item, true);
            item.GotKeyboardFocus += OnGotKeyboardFocus;
        }
        else {
            FocusManager.SetIsFocusScope(item, false);
            item.GotKeyboardFocus -= OnGotKeyboardFocus;
        }
    }

    private static void OnGotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e) {
        if (SettingKeyboardFocus) {
            return;
        }

        var focusedElement = e.NewFocus as Visual;

        for (var d = focusedElement; d != null; d = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(d) as Visual) {
            if (FocusManager.GetIsFocusScope(d)) {
                SettingKeyboardFocus = true;

                try {
                    d.SetValue(FocusManager.FocusedElementProperty, focusedElement);
                }
                finally {
                    SettingKeyboardFocus = false;
                }

                if (!(bool)d.GetValue(IsEnhancedFocusScopeProperty)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your XAML you just need to set this attached property instead of standard `IsFocusScope` property:

```
<ItemsControl my:FocusExtensions.IsEnhancedFocusScope="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=TheWindow, Path=ListOStrings}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

It will work as you expect the focus scope to work.